# Store HTML Dropdown Value as Python Variable

Tags: python, html, sql-server, flask

I would like to simply print the result of an HTML dropdown menu in python for testing purposes. The dropdown menu is a python list of all possible customer id's collected from a database table. I am new to using templating engines, so I'm not sure if I'm accessing the value in HTML correctly. The value should return a number, but it returns "None" instead.

Python:

```
@app.route('/customers/update-customer', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def update_customer():
   # get customer id from gui dropdown
   sql = "SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, C_FNAME, C_LNAME FROM Customer"
   cursor.execute(sql)
   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   customers = []
   for customer in rows:
       customers.append(customer[0])
   if request.method == 'POST':
       customer = request.form.get('customer') # FIXME
       print(customer)
   return render_template('updatecustomer.html', customers = customers)
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="customer">
          {% for customer in customers %}
          <option value="{{ customer }}" SELECTED>{{ customer }}</option>"
          {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Result:

```
None
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2021 08:47:07] "POST /customers/update-customer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

[Web App GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qEYO.png)

If I press submit with id 89, python must print "89" in the terminal.

Comment: `<select name="colours">`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning typo, changes made.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have `<form>` element in your html and this element should have `action` (that points to your endpoint that should process this form) and method.
Second: if you want to retrieve a "customer" key from form, your `<select>` tag should have `name="customer"`. Value for this key will be the value of selected `<option>`

So it should be

```
<form method="POST" action="/customers/update-customer"> # read about jinja2 and url_for to replace this url
    <select name="customer">
        Your values
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: There is more in the HTML file, but I have only included the problem area. Edited to include form element.

Comment: You don't need `name` attribute in `option`, only in `select`. And you don't need `method` and `action` in `select`, these attributes should be in `form` (see my example). It should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by doing something like

```
import pprint 

template_to_see = render_template('updatecustomer.html', customers = customers)

pprint.pprint(template_to_see)
```